# Is there a mouse event for-"clicking and dragging over elements"?

Tags: javascript, css, events, mouseevent

So actually I am creating a basic level sketch-box in which when mouse is clicked and dragged over several elements(divs) then their color changes.

I have been able to create the effects in which the color changes when (1)the mouse is hovered over(using mouseover event) an element and (2)when an element is clicked(using mousedown event). But both of these ways have problems as using mouseover brings the problem that their cannot be breaks in coloring(all the hovered elements get colored) and with mousedown the problem is that it is just too much clicking.

So I am looking for a way in which if I click and then drag my mouse over several divs then all those divs should be colored. Thus ideas regarding the same.

```
const n = +(prompt('Enter a number between 1 and 100'));
const sketchArea = document.querySelector('.sketchArea');

**function addColor(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    e.target.classList.add('black');
}**

for(let i=0;i<(n*n);i++){
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('box');
    **//div.addEventListener('mousedown',addColor)
    //div.addEventListener('mouseover',addColor)**
    sketchArea.appendChild(div);
}

sketchArea.setAttribute('style', `grid-template-columns: repeat(${n},1fr); grid-template-rows:repeat(${n},1fr);`);
```

This is the javascript file. In this I am creating a sketch area of n*n(input taken using prompt) divs and adding event listeners to each of them so their color changes when an event occurs.

Comment: my english is quite bad so i think you want to use both onmouseover and onmousedown <-- this will help you check if user want coloring or not by change var draw = 1; if(draw == 1){coloring}

Comment: And what event will cause the change in variable draw?                                                                I don't actually want to use both mouseover and mousedown events, I just want to create the effect that we get when we use ms paint(like the the pencil tool only draws if we click and drag the mouse and only those areas are colored till where we dragged our mouse).

Comment: Onmousedown will change it and when onmouseup draw will = 0 so it can't draw anymore

Comment: Thank you! I think it will do the trick.